# Why do I get "no method named push found for type Option" with a vector of vectors?

Tags: rust

I tried to use a `String` vector inside another vector:

```
let example: Vec<Vec<String>> = Vec::new();

for _number in 1..10 {
    let mut temp: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    example.push(temp);
}
```

I should have 10 empty `String` vectors inside my vector, but:

```
example.get(0).push(String::from("test"));
```

fails with

```
error[E0599]: no method named `push` found for type `std::option::Option<&std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:20
  |
9 |     example.get(0).push(String::from("test"));
  |                    ^^^^
```

Why does it fail? Is it even possible to have an vector "inception"?

Comment: Read the error message a little closer. Note the difference between `example.get(0)` and `example[0]`.

Comment: lol, tried example[0] before, didn't seem to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the documentation of types and methods before you use them. At the very least, look at the function's *signature*. For [`slice::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get):

```
pub fn get<I>(&self, index: I) -> Option<&<I as SliceIndex<[T]>>::Output>
where
    I: SliceIndex<[T]>,
```

While there's some generics happening here, the important part is that the return type is an `Option`. An `Option<Vec>` is not a `Vec`.

Refer back to [*The Rust Programming Language*'s chapter on enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-00-enums.html) for more information about enums, including `Option` and `Result`. If you wish to continue using the semantics of `get`, you will need to:

1. Switch to `get_mut` as you want to mutate the inner vector.
2. Make `example` mutable.
3. Handle the case where the indexed value is missing. Here I use an `if let`.

```
let mut example: Vec<_> = std::iter::repeat_with(Vec::new).take(10).collect();

if let Some(v) = example.get_mut(0) {
    v.push(String::from("test"));
}
```

If you want to kill the program if the value is not present at the index, the shortest thing is to use the index syntax `[]`:

```
example[0].push(String::from("test"));
```

Comment: thank you, confused from Java, where you use get for ArrayLists/Vectors